# Where is /etc/init.d/vsftpd on macos?

Tags: macos, vsftpd

I would like to perform the equivalent in linux of 
sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart

Comment: Try `service vsftpd restart` and see if that does it.

Comment: Where would service be in this case ?

Comment: Run the `whereis vsftpd` and see if that will disclose the install location of the binary executable you are looking for.

Comment: neither which nor whereis return anything for vsftpd for me. the vsftpd.conf file however is in /usr/local/etc.

Answer (score 1):

To use chroot, vsftpd requires root privileges, so you will need to run
  sudo vsftpd.
You should be certain that you trust any software you grant root privileges.

The vsftpd.conf file must be owned by root or vsftpd will refuse to start:
  sudo chown root /usr/local/etc/vsftpd.conf

To have launchd start vsftpd now and restart at startup:
  sudo brew services start vsftpd
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  sudo vsftpd

**So your vsftpd.conf file is in /usr/local/etc.**

Comment: I get vsftpd command not found.
I then tried sudo /usr/local/Cellar/vsftpd/3.0.3/sbin/vsftpd but got 
500 OOPS: config file not owned by correct user, or not a file